# Почему не работает order в flex в @media?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

```js
$("main").addClass("clear");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

html,
body header:first-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header,
main,
menu,
footer,
aside,
section,
article {
  display: block;
}

header,
menu,
main,
footer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: .2% auto;
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 13px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 13px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 13px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

header,
footer {
  min-height: 120px;
}

main {
  box-shadow: none;
}

aside,
article,
section {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 13px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 13px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 13px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}

aside {
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 150px;
}

article {
  width: 44%;
  min-height: 220px;
  margin-left: .5%;
  margin-right: .5%;
}

section {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  section {
    display: none !important;
  }
  aside,
  article {
    float: left;
  }
  aside {
    width: 30%;
    min-height: 150px;
  }
  article {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
  }
  article {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  aside {
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  header
</header>
<menu>
  menu
</menu>
<main>
  <aside class="">
    aside
  </aside>
  <article class="">
    article
  </article>
  <section>
    section
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: ставлю для aside -order 2 , а он "скатина" так и стоит первым

Comment: Проверил, aside идёт вторым при ширине меньше 640px, как и задумано.

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/21h7/T9fY99j9b  вот скрин - смотрите

Comment: и в снипете всё тип топ , а в броузере нет , вендорные  префиксы делал и не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("main").addClass("clear");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 70%;
}

header {
  background: red;
  min-height: 120px;
}

menu {
  background: blue;
}

main {
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

main * {
  min-height: 200px;
}

aside {
  background: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  order: 2;
}

article {
  background: brown;
  width: 40%;
  order: 3;
}

section {
  background: chocolate;
  width: 25%;
  order: 1;
}

footer {
  background: pink;
  min-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  section {
    display: none;
  }
  article {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  aside {
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <header> header </header>
  <menu> menu </menu>
  <main>
    <aside> aside </aside>
    <article> article </article>
    <section> section </section>
  </main>
  <footer> footer </footer>
</div>
```

Ответ мой в том что надо было изначально верстать на Flexbox — решение нашёл самостоятельноб, пример в сниппете